# Timeout error in VB.NET while running a sql script

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if someone can help me figure why I am getting this error from a simple stored procedure that I created in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am trying to obtain data and insert it into a temporary table.  if it is a timeout issue, how can I increase the timeout length to 420 seconds.  to my understanding the timeout is good for only 30 seconds.

this is the error in its entirety:

### Server Error in '/WebSite9' Application.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1951450
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849003
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +130
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.GetData() +38
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +153
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +55
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +69
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim cmd = connection.CreateCommand()    
cmd.CommandTimeout = 420
```

Use the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property.

Comment: You need to post your code in order for me to tell you that.  I assume you're using a `SqlCommand` object in order to execute your SQL, right?  If so, just set the `CommandTimeout` property on the command.

Answer (score 1):

Set the timeout in ASP code

VB.NET:

```
Dim objCmd = conn.CreateCommand()
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 420
```

or Classic:

```
set con = createObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.open connectionString
con.commandTimeout = 420
```

I would review your execution plan on your query as well to determine if you have some table scans going on resulting in a poor performing query.